# Как загрузить обратно полный дамп в phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

сделал фулл экспорт всех баз данных. теперь хочу делать импорт, ругается что некоторые базы данных уже существуют, типа information_schema. Что делать?

p.s. Есть вариант удалить из файла экспорта упоминание об этой базе, но это какое-то кривоt решение

Answer (score 2):

**information_schema** это служебная база данных в MySQL. В нормальных условиях у вас не должно возникать необходимости полностью ее импортировать в базу данных.